# What does FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION mean?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller, field-integrity-exception

when I try to save my aura controller this pop up doesn't allow me to save it

Failed to save demo.js: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.demo: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':' [22, 9]: 'action': Source

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! By the way, if you want a more specific answer to your problem, make sure you include your code. You can [edit] your question to provide the code. Also, if you haven't yet, take some time to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour].

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the Aura JavaScript parser when you have a typo in your source code.

For example, you might get such an error from code like this:

```
({
  method1 function(c, e, h) {
  }
})
```

Here, the error is saying that there's a missing ":":

```
({
  method1: function(c, e, h) {
  }
})
```

This isn't the exact message that you've gotten, but the principle is the same. You'll need to find the error in your source code and correct it. The error might be caused by a different line of code entirely, so you should use your IDE to discover the error; look for weird syntax highlights or red squiggly marks that indicate errors.